# Draw complex table in figma

Tags: figma

I have tried drawing this complex table in figma. I am tired of going from one tutorial to another, any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is a picture of the table[image]

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Figma is not exactly a tool for drawing large or complex tables.

Yet, here is the methodology I would recommend, which is to break your table into rows. And each row opens the top border.
[image]

There are many other resources about this topic by searching "drawing table Figma" on Google. Articles such as [this one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/09/creating-tables-in-figma/) can help you a lot.